# Meteor client side upsert not allowed

Tags: meteor

I am currently building my first Meteor application and am having some trouble with upserting documents into a collection client side.

I am looking to update a document if it is in the collection already and insert one if there is not. Currently my code looks like this

```
UserData.upsert(
            {
                // Selector
                _id: Meteor.users.findOne({})._id
            },
            {
                // Modifier
                $set: {
                    user: Meteor.users.findOne({}),
                    currentquestions: currentQuestion
                }
            }


        );
```

Which is then allowed by

```
 UserData.allow({
insert: function (userId) {
    // the user must be logged in, and the document must be owned by the user
    return (userId != null);
},
update: function (userId) {
    // the user must be logged in, and the document must be owned by the user
    return (userId != null);
},
upsert: function (userId) {
    // the user must be logged in, and the document must be owned by the user
    return (userId != null);
}
```

})

This works for insert and update. But for upsert i get the following error

```
Error: allow: Invalid key: upsert
```

Ofcourse I can use If/Else with Insert/Update but that seems to be a bit redundant when .upsert should do the exact trick. **Does anyone know how to allow a .upsert client side?**

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178078/meteor-allow-upsert

Comment: Why aren't you just using `Meteor.userId()`? `findOne` could grab a random user.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's because you don't define a separate allow rule for `upsert`, only for insert, update, and remove (http://docs.meteor.com/#allow). Furthermore, "upsert is the same as calling update with the upsert option set to true (..)" (http://docs.meteor.com/#upsert).

So the up short is: just make sure your rule for updating is correct.